# How to quickly find an $x$ that works?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When asked to prove if this is true or not $\exists x \in\Bbb R$, $x^2 + 29x + 209 \leq 0$, it can easily be done by saying when $x = -15$ it works. But how to find that $x = -15$?

For any "there exists" problem that shows up on a test, how to find one that just works?

Answer (score 1):

The vertex of a parabola $ax^2+bx+c$ is at $-\frac b{2a}$.  Your parabola opens upward because $a \gt 0$, so if any point has a value less than zero the vertex does.  You can just check whether $-14.5$ leads to a value less than zero.  If it does, you have found a value.  If not, there is none.

Comment: But we aren't allowed calculators in our exams and this seems a little tough

Comment: @ming:  see the new answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solve for the equality and then find the roots, then by dropping the value of the roots will yield the inequality.

Here $x^2+29x+209=0$ gives, $x=\frac{-29\pm \sqrt{29^2-4\times 209}}{2}$ i.e. $x=\frac{-29\pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$. For these values the equality holds.

Now, taking $\sqrt5\approx 2$ we get, $x\approx \frac{-31}{2}=-15.5$ or, $\frac{-27}{2}=-13.5$, then for these values we have a strict inequality. You may take integer part for strict inequality.

Comment: I thought this too but we are not allowed calculators in our exams

Comment: @rowcol You don't need calculators to find the square root of 5. I didn't as you can see me roughly used the value $\sqrt5\approx2$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f(x)=x^2+29x+209$ is a quadric, then you could compute its roots $r_{1}=-\dfrac{29-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $r_{2}=-\dfrac{29+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Then you can verify that $f(x) \leq 0$ when $r_{1} \leq x \leq r_{2}$.

A way to do this, is factoring and evaluating when $f$ is positive and when $f$ is negative.

Another way is using Rolle's theorem and the continuity of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Going back to the original question – proving if $x \in \mathbb R$, $x^2+29x+209 ≤0$ is true, you don't need to find an $x$ that works.

The discriminant $b^2-4ac$ is $(29)^2-4(1)(209) > 0$, so there are two real roots. Since all polynomials are differentiable, there must be some $x$ that is $≤ 0$ between the two roots.

Answer (score 0):

$y=x^2+29x +209$, a parabola , opening upward, has a minimum at the vertex.

Complete the square:

$y = (x+29/2)^2-(29/2)^2 +209.$

Choose $x=-29/2$ (why?).

P.S. Check if $-(29/2)^2+209 \le 0.$

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I'd say the numbers are a bit large and try to substitute to fix that up.  Since $209$ is between $14^2$ and $15^2,$ I might try $x=z-14$ or  $x=z-15$.  Take the former:

$$x^2+29x+209 = (z-14)^2+29(z-14)+209$$ $$ =z^2+z-1.$$

So it's now easy to see $z=0$ gives a negative value.  So that means $x=14$ works in the original expression.